# For loop "jumps to the end" for no apparent reason?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

In a Javascript program I have an object with the following two (simplified) functions:

```
this.do_A = function() {
    var nothing_changed = false;
    while (!nothing_changed) {
        nothing_changed = true;
        for (var column=0; column<this.columns; column++) {
            for (var row=0; row<this.rows; row++) {
                nothing_changed = nothing_changed && this.do_B(row, column);
            }
        }
    } 
}

this.do_B = function(row, column) {
    nothing_changed = true;
    if (this[row][column] == null) {
        nothing_changed = false;
    }
    return nothing_changed;
}
```

When running this code something very strange happens when do_B returns false, and hence nothing_changed becomes false - when reaching again the

```
for (var row=0; row<this.rows; row++)
```

line, the `row` variable becomes immediately `this.rows` and hence the inner loop terminates. Moreover, it happens in the subsequent runs of the outer loops - `row` is initialized to be `0`, then becomes `this.rows` immediately and the inner loop ends again.

I have no reason what can cause this. I have tried simplifying the functions as much as possible and it keeps happening.

Comment: Your first nothing_changed is a local variable, your second one is a global variable - is that on purpose?

Comment: You are setting `nothing_changed` to `true` on the first line of the while loop. This is breaking the condition of `nothing_changed` being `false` for the while loop.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
for (var row=0; row<this.rows; row++)
{
  nothing_changed = nothing_changed && this.do_B(row, column);
}
```

When `this.do_B(row, column)` returns `false`, `nothing_changed` will be `false`
, and when it loops again and reaches `nothing_changed = nothing_changed && this.do_B(row, column)`, because `nothing_changed` is `false`, the second expression `this.do_B(row, column)` will not be evaluated, so `nothing_changed` will always be `false` until `row` reaches `this.rows`.

Comment: This is called short-circuit evaluation.

Answer (score 0):

How do you know the `for` loop jumps to the end? If you're checking by searching for invocations of `do_B`, then you need to account for the fact that in the following expression:

```
nothing_changed && this.do_B(row, column)
```

if `nothing_changed` is already `false`, then `this.do_B(row, column)` will not be called because, no matter what the RHS evaluates to, the expression as a whole will evaluate to `false`.

This is known as [short-circuiting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

Perhaps that's what's going on? If you put debug output directly inside the `for` loop, I'm sure you'll see it continuing to the end of its prescribed number of iterations:

```
for (var column=0; column<this.columns; column++) {
  for (var row=0; row<this.rows; row++) {
    console.log(column + "|" + row);
    nothing_changed = nothing_changed && this.do_B(row, column);
  }
}
```